# Reading result of create database in mysql from Bash shell script

Tags: mysql, bash

I am creating a database in a shell script using

```
mysql -u$username -p$password -e " create database testdb"
```

I want to store the result of this statement to make decisions in shell script based on its success or failure.

Even during insert statements i do not get any return value
how can is store the result after executing  create database / insert statements in shell script?

Answer (score 0):

use the following command substitution syntax:

```
var=$(command-name-here arg1 arg2...)
```

So for your command you can do something like this,

```
output=$(mysql -u$username -p$password -e " create database testdb")
echo "$output"
```